# Boot loop on thumb drive, but flash drive works fine

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

I have two live USB drives containing the same operating system, Ubuntu 10.04 with legacy boot.

When I plug those drives in (using Ubuntu), one is detected as a "Thumb drive" (Pen drive?)  and the other is detected as a "Flash drive". The thumb drive is shown as the purple icon, and flash drive is shown as the normal flash drive. (*see image below*). The thumb drive is a fairly new USB, whereas the flash drive is one year old or so. They are however, both Kingston USBs.

[image: formerly i57.tinypic.com/2q3ni9i.png]

The one marked as thumb drive goes into boot loop on some PCs that I have tested, where the normal flash drive works fine. All the machines where it loops are windows 8 PCs, however, most other win8 PCs boots the thumb drive without problems. All the machines worked fine with the flash drive.

- They are both a disk file systems, FAT32.
- I have tried to reformat the thumb drive, but it has no effect.
- The boot loop happens at the computer manufactor screen, as this screen keeps looping (Where you normally would enter bios, but which is impossible as long as the thumb drive is plugged in). Some computer also only get stuck at this screen, like it's frozen.
- It's impossible to enter BIOS, boot menu or anything else

(I think) I just figured out that the purple icon as shown in the image above is a pen drive! The other one is a flash drive. I read about the differences on these two [here](http://www.ehow.com/list_7194950_differences-flash-drives-pen-drives.html), but it doesn't really give me a proper explaination. It sounds from that page that both of my volumes are pen drives.

My questions are therefore:

- Why does the boot loop only happen when using the thumb drive?
- And why does it loop only on specific PCs? (They were all windows 8 machines)
- Why do they appear as two different icons in ubuntu?
- Is there really a difference between thumb drive and flash drive?
- Am I missing something here?
- Can I somehow format or convert the thumb drive to a flash drive?

Comment: Are both drives formatted with the same FileSystem? What FileSystem do you use?

Comment: To help you we'll need more detail. What exactly do you mean by the loop? Can you provide bootlog? Does the bootloader load correctly on all machines? The question about FileSystem still stands.

Comment: I have two nearly identical Sandisk Cruzer USB drives, one 4 GB and other 8 GB. On Linux, one is displayed with the flash drive icon and other with the generic USB storage icon. The only difference, AFAICT, is the file system. I have asked [a question on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462453/meaning-of-different-icons-for-usb-flash-drives) about this.

Comment: I have edited the post a little to answer your questions. I don't have a boot log right now, but I can provide it. Is this the correct way to find the boot log? http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/30364-check-your-pc-shutdown-startup-log-forensic-way.html

Comment: Please don't use `[EDIT]` tags or similar here. The full revision history of the post including the differences between revisions is available by clicking the "edited" link below the post. Just add (or replace) content as appropriate based on what's needed to answer the question or clarify the answer. You can `@`-ping people in the comments in order to draw their attention to a revised post, although I strongly suggest not overdoing that.

Comment: @Michael Körling Thank you, I didn't know that.